# roslaunch catkin_ros_wrapper catkin_node.launch run terminal gets stuck when i run this code

Tags: ubuntu, ros

host:= my_ip
I can ping this ip, but the gazebo does not open. A message should appear like Ros Wrapper has been started, but it does not.
instead I get waiting for connection -XXXXXXXX
I'm using ros-melodic ubuntu 18.04.
I am not working in virtual machine.
There is a setting.json file in my airsim.
Some sites wrote that they could not connect with the API, but I can't find how to provide this connection. I would appreciate it if you could help.

[Waiting for connection- XXXXX appears on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7JmM.jpg)

Comment: This question is very confusing. Thanks for providing most of your setup, but it seems you're having an issue with airsim? I can't really tell what you're trying to do with this IP address. Gazebo is usually a node on your own computer, where I assume you're running the simulation. If you want help, be much more specific in how to reproduce your problem, what were the steps you tried, and what the setup is.

Comment: By the way, welcome! I Recommend you read this article, it'll help people help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask